# Store file into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I'm working on a POC to save a file (binary) into SQL Server database.
The Laravel documentation don't have anything related to saving binary to database using Eloquent.

Comment: Personally I recommend against storing files inside a database. It has a number of long-term impacts: faster database growth; increased storage costs; longer backup times; increased backup storage costs; longer restore times, which leads to pressure on RPO and RTO. Consider storing files in AWS S3 or Azure Blob (where storage costs are far cheaper and you don't have to manage backups/redundancy) and store only references to the files in the database instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it's not a proper way to save files in database but still you can. First add binary column to your model's migration:

```
$table->binary('bfile');
```

This will make a `BLOB` field in database.

Then just read contents of that file and store it in model:

```
$model = new SampleModel();
$model->bfile = $contents;
$model->save()
```